# Применение CSS к pnp Carousel control

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

столкнулся с такой проблемой - не применяется стиль для контента Карусели, в чем может быть причина? На первом скриншоте объявляется стиль carouselImageContent, потом он подключается для контейнера в самом контроле, но на выходе я получаю такую же схлопнутую карусель, если через код элемента принудительно добавить стиль, то работает все корректно.[image: Объявление стилей][1]]

Comment: Что там тильда делает?

Comment: @Qwertiy, убрал тильду, без изменений

Comment: @MaksimKrom Не достаточно информации по одному css сложно сказать почему именно так, попробуйте убрать проблем между 348px !important, но это конечно врятли поможет, а так сбросьте пожалуйста код компоненты или html карусели.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем кто принял участие, нашел решение: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264098/problem-with-changing-in-the-scss-file. Может быть кому пригодиться, дело заключается в том, что для того, что бы система подхватила css стили для элемента карусели, нужно сверху в div закинуть корневой класс стилей. Выглядит это вот так. Надеюсь, что кому то поможет, т.к. для меня это решение было не очевидным.  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст ответа можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, не совсем понял, что тут конкретно нужно будет копировать и читать текстом. Мне лучше вставить код разметки в текст ответа?